# How to reference a layout schema

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, schema

In Android Studio I have the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entry_entry"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="4dip"
        android:textSize="8pt"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.42"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance_entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="2dip"
            android:textSize="8pt"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/miles_entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="2dip"
            android:text="m"
            android:textSize="7pt"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/folder_entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="4dip"
            android:textSize="6pt"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/file_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="6pt"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This layout is copied from an app that worked in Eclipse.

When I "Validate" the xml file I get the following errors:

> Error:cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element
>   'LinearLayout'.
>
> Error:External resource http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android is
>   not registered
>
> Error:Premature end of file.

It seems that the answer will be to register the schema. How do I do that? (I have googled that question but not found an answer.)

Comment: The outermost LinearLayout is not closed. Could you add `</LinearLayout>` at the very end and try again?

Comment: Thanks, Mehmed. '</LinearLayout> is already there at the end of the xml file. I failed to copy it into the question. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: It is actually in the "body" of my question but somehow StackOverflow doesn't show it. I'll try editing the question to include the whole layout as a quote rather than code and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry. I've failed to get the whole xml file showing here. Each <LinearLayout> is closed and the xml has been copied straight from an app that does work in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There is no XML schema for layout resources. That is because there is an infinite number of element names (based on arbitrary Java classes) and an infinite number of attribute names.

On the whole, I am not aware of an XML schema for any Android resource type. Layouts are the type most resistant to having such a schema, though.

Comment: But the Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout) includes "<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"". Perhaps I've misused the term schema. So my question should be how do I register the thing (external resource) that Android Studio says is not registered?

Comment: @prepbgg: "But the Android documentation... includes..." -- yes, but that is just to define the namespace. There is no XML schema at that address. "So my question should be how do I register the thing (external resource) that Android Studio says is not registered?" -- I do not know what you are doing. What "Validate" are you referring to that is giving you this message?

Comment: In the Project window under app>res>layout I find the layout xml file. Validate is an option in the context menu that appears when I right-click on the name of the xml file. After I click on Validate a window opens headed Messages which lists the errors that I mentioned in the question. I hoped that if I found out how to "register" the External resource http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android the first error (Error:cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'LinearLayout'.) would be resolved.

Comment: Incidentally another layout (activity-main.xml) in the same project includes <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android". This works without any problems.  Should I perhaps include some reference to a "widget" related to LinearLayout?

Comment: @prepbgg: That's just a bug in Android Studio. The manifest and some resource types cannot be validated this way. I filed [a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158269622), so hopefully Validate will not be presented as an option for XML files where we know up front that validation can never succeed.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the explanation. I tried the Validate option because when I try to include a reference to the layout file in my Kotlin code it's not recognised. I've tried referring just to the layout name, and I've tried preceding it with R.id. but neither works. I'll start a new thread tomorrow with more specific details.

Comment: @prepbgg: Layout resources are referenced as `R.layout.whatever`, for a resource file in `res/layout/whatever.xml`.